# Xcode ->Html5 reading in app

Tags: ios, xcode, html

If I display the html5 webpage in my app and in the page, in the code given to me is a button. I was wondering if there are any possibilities to react on touching event on this button....

example...

text of the page.....------------- some window in here and on the right side of the page is a button which is inside the web page, it is not done in iOS in Xcode and I need to make a reaction method on touching this button. Is there any possibility to do that???

Thanks all to suggestions.

EDIT:

the button is in the website I am loading, so step by step. I load the page and inside the page there are buttons. If I click the button I need to react to it.

Comment: Maybe this is what you need
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422832/listening-for-events-in-a-uiwebview-ios

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want the app to react to a HTML5 button that's being generated within a UIWebView? If so, I would take a look at the UIWebView's delegate

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

Each time a link is pressed, the request gets passed to that delegate. From there you can inspect the link and react to it accordingly.

Comment: oh, thanks but this is not exactly what i need. No no, the button is in the website I am loading, so step by step. I load the page and inside the page there are buttons. If I click the button I need to react to it.

Comment: I guess I'm just not understanding you then. In order to react to a button that's clicked within a webpage, you can use the above delegate method, that or just let the webpage react to it on its own. What do you want to do once the button is clicked?

Comment: launch in app purchase... to be all clear ...I have the webpage shown, and inside the page is button, but this button does't know how to run in app purchase, so i need to react on it......:(

Comment: Your button must be linked to some URL request within the web page. That is what you need to intercept using this method. Is it your web page or an external one.